# WordPress /wp-inlcludes/functions.php: Custom functions/code disappears

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have added two custom written functions to my wordpress code.
One of them uses the add_action() and the other uses the add_filter() function of wordpress.

After deploying the code, both functions work as expected, but after some time (I am not sure how long it takes and what causes wordpress to do so) the code just magically disappears from the file.

I am now wondering

- Why is this happening?
- What can I do so that this won't happen again?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you added custom code in wp-includes/functions.php?

Comment: As mentioned in the title, yes

Comment: you shouldn't make any changes into wp-includes or wp-admin folders these folders will update automatically if your wordpress  is updated. so if you want to make any changes using hooks and actions you can place the code into your current theme's functions.php. that will work as expected and your code won't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you just mentioned that you've added code into /wp-includes/functions.php file. You've used action and filters that's good but your code should be go into active theme's (child theme is the best practice) functions.php file. Files under /wp-admin/ and /wp-includes/ get updated automatically from WP when new update is available (based on settings you have done on your WP setup you can ignore updates as well).

So, your code must be removed by update. Files were overridden by updates. If you have backup copy those code and put it into active theme's functions.php file /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/functions.php is the correct file where you can add the code.

If you have added code into theme's functions.php file make sure you didn't get theme updated otherwise you may lost your work as well that's the reason you can use the Child theme. You can learn how to create child theme here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this happening?

Most probably because someone updated WordPress to latest version. Before you are going to tell me "but I did not press anything, ever!" please bear in mind, that WordPress updates itself automatically. Especially in the newer versions.

Here is nice [article about WordPress automatic updates](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-automatic-updates/). It also describes how to turn this off, but I do not recommend doing so.

> What can I do so that this won't happen again?

Develop custom WordPress plugin, containing your customizations. Here is nice [step by step tutoria](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-wordpress-plugin)l

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice! 
I have already created some custom plugins, but for this specific problem I have, it's not a good solution.
I have added the code to our own custom theme and now it seems to work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't make any changes into **wp-includes and wp-admin folders, these folders will update automatically if your wordpress  is updated.** so **if you want to make any changes using hooks and actions you can place the code into your current theme's functions.php.** that will work as expected and your code won't disappear.